# Oracle SQL time data type

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm looking to store just a time value in a number of columns, but I'm unsure what data type I have to use?
There is currently TIMESTAMP in place, but this seems to store date as well and is useless if I'm trying to store a recorded time from a race.

Any ideas, I've searched around and can't find what I'm looking for.

Thank you for reading!

Comment: Some more information on how you will be using this data and what precision you need will help provide better answers.

Answer (score 6):

The elapsed time for a race should be stored in an `INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND`.

```
SQL> create table runner(
  2    runner_id number primary key,
  3    runner_name varchar2(100),
  4    runner_time interval day to second
  5  );

Table created.

SQL> insert into runner
  2    values( 1, 'Justin', numtodsinterval( 250, 'second' ) );

1 row created.

SQL> select *
  2    from runner;

 RUNNER_ID RUNNER_NAME          RUNNER_TIME
---------- -------------------- ------------------------------
         1 Justin               +00 00:04:10.000000
```

Comment: Docs for [intervals](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements001.htm#sthref167), [`numtodsinterval()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions117.htm), and [`to_dsinterval()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions204.htm) for reference.

Comment: How would I go about changing the datatype of current columns in my table to allow me to store the INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND

Comment: @Max - Is the table empty?  If it is, you can do an `ALTER TABLE` to modify the data type of the column.  Otherwise, you would almost certainly need to add a new column with the proper data type, move the data over (how you do this will depend on the current data type), drop the old column, and, if so desired, rename the new column.

Comment: Thanks for your help, worked a treat! 
Is it possible to do a SUM query on two columns (both of INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND datatype)?
If so how do I do it? Can't seem to find anything that makes sense to me.

Answer (score 3):

`TIMESTAMP` and `DATETIME` aren't appropriate here. What you're trying to store isn't a *single point* in time, but an *interval* of time. Oracle 9i and later have support for such intervals. Try using `INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND`:

```
INTERVAL '3 12:30:06.7' DAY TO SECOND(1)
```

Reference: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/master-oracles-time-interval-datatypes/6085801